# How can we set Proxy setting for Provisioning of Azure IOT device

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub

We are using this repo : https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node

We are trying to setup a DPS service for Azure Iot hub, we want to setup proxy for Provisioning through X509, In the Sample code : "register_x509.js"

We are using "`var Transport = require('azure-iot-provisioning-device-mqtt').MqttWs;`" library. In that, there is function call "setTransportOptions" and we sending our proxy agent as a permeant there :

```
var transport = new Transport();
transport.setTransportOptions({webSocketAgent:new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.HTTP_PROXY)})
var securityClient = new X509Security(registrationId, deviceCert);
var deviceClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.create(
provisioningHost,
idScope,
transport,
securityClient
);

// Register the device. Do not force a re-registration.
deviceClient.register(function (err, result) {
if (err) {
console.log("error registering device: " + err);
} else {
console.log("registration succeeded");
console.log("assigned hub=" + result.assignedHub);
console.log("deviceId=" + result.deviceId);
}
```

the initial tunneling is not happening due to which the connection is fialing. We also saw in documentation, that Azure SDK has a proxy filter which automatically take Proxy variable from environment, we tried that as well but still same issue. Can anyone please suggest a way for this use case.

Error we received : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: socket hang up

Comment: Hello All, I found the issue, the Mqtt over websocket library ( require('azure-iot-provisioning-device-mqtt').MqttWs ) has a bug where it is not setting transport option at library level, you all can refer this bug : https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/issues/794  for further knowledge, Solution is to switch to amqp over websocket, it very similar to mqtt over websocket just use : var Transport = require('azure-iot-provisioning-device-amqp').AmqpWs;